# Text gradient on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I created a gradient for text that works great on chrome and I have been trying to have the text display the same way in firefox using `-moz-` without success.

Is there a way to acomplish this same effect for firefox?

Here is the css:

```
body h3 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #48e0ff, #ffffff);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #48e0ff, #ffffff);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, while background-clip is a valid CSS3 property, the text value is non-standard. A common workaround for non-webkit browsers is to use SVGs instead.

I found a jQuery plugin for handling this cross browser. It does seems a little heavy though.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://www.myadzel.ru/tests/html/text-background/)**</kbd> <kbd>**[Github](https://github.com/myadzel/patternizer)**</kbd>